# Social.java and SocialRunner.java

Tags: java

I am doing a social security program where you take apart a SS #, remove the hyphens (-), and parse the 3 parts into integers and add up.

Here is the main runner:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class SocialRunner
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
      Social social = new Social("1-1-1");
        //add test cases
      //social.Social("1-1-1");
      //social.chopAndAdd();
       //boolean check = stringlivesmatter.checkEquality();
       out.println(social);

    }
}
```

And here is the main program:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Social
{
   private String socialNum;
   private String ssNum1, ssNum2, ssNum3, sub;
   private int sum;

    public Social()
    {
    }

    public Social(String soc)
    {
      socialNum = soc;

    }
    public void setWord(String w)
    {

      /*String ssNum1 = socialNum.substring(0,socialNum.indexOf("-"));
      String ssNum2 = socialNum.substring(socialNum.indexOf("-")+1,socialNum.indexOf("-"));
      String ssNum3 = socialNum.substring(socialNum.indexOf("-")+1,socialNum.indexOf("-"));
      */
    }

    public void chopAndAdd()
    {
        sub = socialNum;
      ssNum1 = socialNum.substring(0,socialNum.indexOf("-"));
      ssNum2 = socialNum.substring(socialNum.indexOf("-")+1,socialNum.lastIndexOf("-"));
      ssNum3 = socialNum.substring(socialNum.lastIndexOf("-")+1,0);
      sum = Integer.parseInt(ssNum1) + Integer.parseInt(ssNum2) + Integer.parseInt(ssNum3);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
      sum = Integer.parseInt(ssNum1) + Integer.parseInt(ssNum2) + Integer.parseInt(ssNum3);
      /*
      String ssNum1 = socialNum.substring(0,socialNum.indexOf("-"));
      String ssNum2 = socialNum.substring(socialNum.indexOf("-")+1,socialNum.indexOf("-"));
      String ssNum3 = socialNum.substring(socialNum.indexOf("-")+1,socialNum.indexOf("-"));
      sum = Integer.parseInt(ssNum1) + Integer.parseInt(ssNum2) + Integer.parseInt(ssNum3);
      */
        return "SS# " + socialNum + " has a total of " + sum + "\n";
    }
}
```

With the way the two programs above are written, I am given a runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Social.toString(Social.java:46)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
    at SocialRunner.main(SocialRunner.java:20)
```

If I comment/delete:

```
sum = Integer.parseInt(ssNum1) + Integer.parseInt(ssNum2) + Integer.parseInt(ssNum3);
```

from

```
public String toString()
```

I get:

```
SS# 1-1-1 has a total of 0
```

How can I avoid a runtime or logic error?

Comment: By setting `ssNum1`, `ssNum2` etc. to some value. At the moment they are null which can't be parsed to an Integer

Comment: You are only calling the constructor `Social(String soc)` which does nothing. You need to call the methods in the `main`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to remove the dashes to get your number.

```
public void chopAndAdd()
{
    String con = socialNum.replaceAll("-", "");
    sum = Integer.parseInt(ssNum1) ;

}
```

You probably may need to modify this as well

```
public String toString()
{
    this.chopAndAdd();
    return "SS# " + socialNum + " has a total of " + sum + "\n";
}
```

and

```
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    Social social = new Social("1-1-1");
    social.chopAndAdd();
    out.println(social.toString(););

}
```

Take your time go through and analyse very well to your understanding

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor in Social as follows so that the ssNum variables are actually set.

```
  public Social(String soc)
  {
    socialNum = soc;
    String[] chunks = soc.split("-");
    ssNum1 = chunks[0];
    ssNum2 = chunks[1];
    ssNum3 = chunks[2];
  }
```

Using `String.split` will break up the ssn into a `String[3]`, each element of which will contain the numbers excluding what you split on, in this case hyphens.

e.g. `[123, 12, 1234]`

Then all you need to do is parse them and sum them up.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String socialString = "123-12-1234";
    System.out.println(chopAndAdd(socialString));
  }

  public static int chopAndAdd(String s)
  {
    String[] chunks = s.split("-");
    int first = Integer.parseInt(chunks[0]);
    int second = Integer.parseInt(chunks[1]);
    int third = Integer.parseInt(chunks[2]);
    return first + second + third;
  }
```